# Exporting a function within a class in Typescript

Tags: typescript, export

I am trying to export a function inside of a class in Typescript. I am able to export the class, and use it as an import inside of another class. However, when I try to use the function, it gives me the error as follows

> Property 'formatBytes' does not exist on type 'typeof Landing'.

I am attempting to export the function `formatBytes` inside the `Landing` class  and use it as `Landing.formatBytes` inside the `Modules` class.

Exported class

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default class Landing extends React.Component<{}, SomeState> {
public formatBytes(bytes: number, decimals: number): string {

return 'something';
}

public componentDidMount(): void {

// code
}


public render(): JSX.Element {
const { items } = this.state;

return (
  <div>

  </div>
);
}
}
```

Imported class

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Landing from './Landing'

export default class Modules extends React.Component<
{},
IDetailsListModulesState
> {

constructor(props: {}) {
super(props);

const _columns: IColumn[] = [
  {
    onRender: (item: IDetailsListModuleItem) => {
      return (
        <span>
          {Landing.formatBytes(item.sizeDifference, 3)}
        </span>
      );
    }
  },
];

this.state = {
};
}

public componentDidMount(): void {

}

public render(): JSX.Element {

}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The Landing class must be instantiated in order for you to use the `formatBytes` method.  Either instantiate a new instance of Landing by doing:

```js
const myLanding = new Landing();
myLanding.formatBytes(item.sizeDifference, 3);
```

Or make formatBytes static by writing `public static formatBytes...`